# can i call my apex class by just the url

Tags: apex, rest-api, class, workbench

Here is my  ( i have tested with workbench and it does work)
URL to call :

```
/services/apexrest/ContactUpdatetService.SetContactInactive
```

my json:

```
{
"contactId":"1234",
}
```

Can I just call it by doing something like this?

```
*salesforceurl*/services/apexrest/ContactUpdatetService.SetContactInactive?contactId=1234
```

Comment: It depends on how your apex webservice is defined. Please [edit] your question to show us the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so "automatically." You can, however, check RestContext.request.params to get the value:

```
String param = RestContext.request.params.get('contactId');
```

This requires some modification to your Apex code.

Comment: would i need string param on my apex class to read my url when trying to do this via url: *salesforceurl*/services/apexrest/ContactUpdatetService.SetContactInactive?contactId=1234

Comment: @LaurenTruby Not sure what you're asking?